# Spring Boot Rest API + JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, architecture

I have a CRUD based application, which uses Spring Boot REST Services and JPA. For JPA we have POJO objects mapped to RBMS - PostgreSQL.

Some of my pages require data to be fetched using joins of multiple POJO objects. I just wanted to know what is a good architectural practice to do the same. Following are some of the options i have been informed of, but not sure what are the pros and cons of each especially for a large data volume application.

1. Use Transient Variables in POJOs and use JPA joins
2. Use additional Spring View Objects to combine POJOs
3. Write native/HQL to join tables/POJOs

Any insight would be helpful. If any more details required from me, would be glad to provide.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to go with Entity Mappings.

- This will enable you to easily fetch the parent and its nested entities using either JPA methods or using hibernate.
- You can also specify the fetch type to actually control the behaviour of this fetch.
- In case, you are looking for any complex joins or fetch patterns, Entity Graphs and HQL will be very useful.